# Using boost::asio for simple udp communication

Tags: c++, sockets, boost, udp

This is a simple problem, but I can't seem to figure out what I am doing wrong.  I am attempting to read data sent to a port on a client using Boost and I have the following code which sets up 1) the UDP client, 2) a buffer for reading to and 3) an attempt to read from the socket:

```
// Set up the socket to read UDP packets on port 10114
boost::asio::io_service io_service;
udp::endpoint endpoint_(udp::v4(), 10114);
udp::socket socket(io_service, endpoint_);

// Data coming across will be 8 bytes per packet
boost::array<char, 8> recv_buf;

// Read data available from port
size_t len = socket.receive_from(
            boost::asio::buffer(recv_buf,8), endpoint_);

cout.write(recv_buf.data(), len);
```

The problem is that the `recieve_from` function never returns.  The server is running on another computer and generating data continuously.  I can see traffic on this port on the local computer using Wireshark.  So, what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: There are may reasons why data wouldn't show up in the application layer.  What OS?

Comment: OS is Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: So, tried listening using netcat via ``nc -luv 10114`` and I get the data I expect.

Answer (score 1):

So, it turns out that I need to listen on that port for connections coming from anywhere.  As such, the endpoint needs to be setup as

```
boost::asio::ip::udp::endpoint endpoint_(boost::asio::ip::address::from_string("0.0.0.0"), 10114);
```

Using this setup, I get the data back that I expect.  And fyi, 0.0.0.0 is the same as `INADDR_ANY`.